# Deleting inline model in Django admin

Tags: django

I am trying to use Django admin to remove an inline model. I get an error saying

> [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']

I check the location where the exception is raised. It seems like the inline model was removed, then a form validation happened on the parent model with the deleted inline model still as value of the form. That caused the failure.

In my admin model, I had a `save_formset` method defined, that called `formset.save(commit=False)`. Is the `commit=False` not telling Django to not delete the related models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a quick look at the code, it seems that the formset [`save`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/forms/models.py#L487) method calls
[`save_existing_objects`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/forms/models.py#L591), which does delete the instances, even if `commit` is `False`.

The documentation [saving objects in the formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) doesn't specify what happens to objects marked for deletion when you specify `commit=False`. It just says:

> Pass `commit=False` to return the unsaved model instances: